# Opening a modal JavaFX Alert from Swing Frame

Tags: java, swing, javafx, modal-dialog

I am currently working on a project that uses a framework that is based on swing. My goal is to add a JavaFX component to this project, but I am having some problems with modal dialogs.

Overall my problem can be simplified as follows -

Swing: I have a `JFrame` containing a button. When I press this button, I want to open a dialog containing some JavaFX code. This new dialog should block and always be on top of the frame.

JavaFX: Here I also have a button. When I press this button, I want to display an `Alert` which should block the Dialog (and therefore also the Swing JFrame).

Currently my solution is to use a `JDialog` containing a `JFXPanel` as "glue" so overall my logic is as follows

- The `JFrame` contains a button that opens a new `JDialog`
- This `JDialog` contains a `JFXPanel` which contains a JavaFX `Scene` containing a JavaFX `Button`
- Pressing this JavaFX `Button` opens an `Alert`

The code is in the bottom of this post.

Currently the `JDialog` works as expected. It blocks the parent frame and is always on top of it.

The JavaFX `Dialog` on the other hand, doesn't work quite as expected. It does block the JavaFX `Scene` (I am not able to press the button multiple times), but it has some problems with the `JDialog`. These are -

1. It is not always on top of it. I am able to bring the `JDialog` on front of my alert
2. It doesn't block it. I am able to close the `JDialog` using the X

My own theory is that the problem is the relation between the `JDialog` and the `JFXPanel`. But I am not quite sure how to link them.

A quick and dirty example:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TestFXInSwing {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton button = new JButton("Open JDialog With JFXPanel");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.err.println("Opening JFXPanel");

            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "JDialog");
            final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            dialog.setModal(true);

            dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            dialog.add(fxPanel);

            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initFX(fxPanel);
                }

                private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
                    Button btn = new Button("Open JavaFX Alert");

                    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent t) {
                            System.err.println("Javafx button pressed");

                            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                            alert.setTitle("Javafx Alert");
                            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
                            alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
                            alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                            Field f;
                            try {
                                f = JFXPanel.class.getDeclaredField("stage");
                                f.setAccessible(true);
                                alert.initOwner((Window) f.get(fxPanel));
                            } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(TestFXInSwing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(TestFXInSwing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(TestFXInSwing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(TestFXInSwing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                            alert.showAndWait();
                        }
                    });

                    StackPane root = new StackPane();
                    root.getChildren().add(btn);

                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
                    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                }
            });

            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }

    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is really between the `JDialog` and the window used for the `Alert`: because you are using windows from two different toolkits, there is no way for them to communicate modality between them. You should probably stick to a single toolkit for the windows, even though the code gets a bit ugly. In other words, since you are using a `JFrame` and `JDialog` already, your JavaFX button should open a Swing/AWT window of some kind.

Comment: You might be right. I was just hoping that the JFXPanel provided something to communicate modality between the two windows.